# Prevent form submission using jQuery and mootools acting in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've the following jQuery function to just check one file input field. I've other form fields too but their validation is taken care of by mootools. If the file input field is invalid then the form should not submit irrespective of whether other form fields are submitted or not, while if the other form fields are invalid then yea ofcourse the form do not get submitted as mootools has that check in place. So i just want the form not to submit if the file input field is not valid.

```
jQuery('#submit').live("click",function() {

valid = true;   
if (jQuery('#jform_resume').val() == '') {
    //jQuery('#controls span').html('please select a file');
    jQuery('#jform_resume-lbl').addClass('invalid');
    jQuery('#jform_resume').addClass('invalid');
    valid = false;
}
else{
    jQuery('#jform_resume-lbl').addClass('valid');
    jQuery('#jform_resume').addClass('valid');
    valid = true;
}
var file = jQuery('input[type="file"]').val();
var exts = ['doc','docx','pdf'];
// first check if file field has any value
if ( file ) {
  // split file name at dot
  var get_ext = file.split('.');
  // reverse name to check extension
  get_ext = get_ext.reverse();
  // check file type is valid as given in 'exts' array
  if ( jQuery.inArray ( get_ext[0].toLowerCase(), exts ) > -1 ){
      jQuery('#jform_resume-lbl').addClass('valid');
      jQuery('#jform_resume').addClass('valid');
      valid = true;
  } else {
      jQuery('#jform_resume-lbl').addClass('invalid');
      jQuery('#jform_resume').addClass('invalid');
      valid = false;
      //alert(get_ext[0]);
  }
}
//check whether browser fully supports all File API
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
{      
    var fsize = jQuery('#jform_resume')[0].files[0].size;

    if(fsize>2097152)
    {
        jQuery('#jform_resume-lbl').addClass('invalid');
        jQuery('#jform_resume').addClass('invalid');
        valid = false;
        //alert(fsize);
    }else{
        jQuery('#jform_resume-lbl').addClass('valid');
        jQuery('#jform_resume').addClass('valid');
        valid = true;
    }
}else{
    alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
}
if (jQuery('#captcha').val() == '') {
    //jQuery('#controls span').html('please select a file');
    jQuery('#jform_captcha-lbl').addClass('invalid');
    jQuery('#captcha').addClass('invalid');
    valid = false;
}
else{
    jQuery('#jform_captcha-lbl').addClass('valid');
    jQuery('#captcha').addClass('valid');
    valid = true;
}
if(!valid){
    ??
}
else{
    ??
}
```

});

Comment: having 2 libraries manage validation on one form independently doesn't make sense and is asking for problems.

Comment: thats how it is as i'm using jform in joomla